# JSonConvert Custom Converter Deserialiation Problem / System.StackoverflowException

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, xamarin.forms, converters

In my Xamarin.Forms App, I need to deserialize a JSon that is provided by an APS.net MVC WebApi. For that, I am using Newtonsoft.Json. The data includes derived classes

```
public abstract class PriceModel : ICloneable
[JsonConverter(typeof(PriceModelConverter))]
public class TimingPriceModel : PriceModel
[JsonConverter(typeof(PriceModelConverter))]
public class ChargingPriceModel : PriceModel
```

EDIT: Here is where I try to deserialize:

```
 var client = new HttpClient();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", access_token);     
            var json = await client.GetStringAsync(string.Format("ServerAdress", _zoneId));
            var Customers = new List<Entities.Customer>();
            try
            { 
                JsonConverter[] converters = { new PriceModelConverter() };
                Customers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Entities.Customer>>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings() { Converters = converters });
            }
```

My custom converter is this:

```
public class PriceModelConverter : JsonConverter
{
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) { return objectType == typeof(PriceModel);}
        public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) { throw new NotImplementedException(); }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null) return null;

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
            {
                var li = new List<PriceModel>();
                var arr = JArray.Load(reader);
                foreach (JObject obj in arr)
                {
                    if (obj["ChargingPriceModel"] != null)
                    {
                        var k = obj.ToObject<ChargingPriceModel>(serializer);
                        li.Add(k);
                    }
                    if (obj["TimingPriceModel"] != null)
                    {
                        var k = obj.ToObject<TimingPriceModel>(serializer);
                        li.Add(k);
                    }
                }

                return li;
            }


            JObject jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
            if (jsonObject["OverallCharges"] != null) return jsonObject.ToObject<ChargingPriceModel>(serializer);
            if (jsonObject["Duration"] != null) return jsonObject.ToObject<TimingPriceModel>(serializer);
            return null;
        }
}
```

EDIT 2: Although the code runs without crushes now, it hits a System.StackoverflowException. I suspect an infinite Loop - maybe I shouln't be passing the serializer to the toObject() method?

I've been trying to figure this out for the last two days now and it prves pretty blocking, so any help / advice is appreciated. My (reduced) Json (From Postman) for a dataset is this:

```
[
{
        "MembershipType": "Abo",
        "ContactData": {
            "Phone1": "Phone",
            "Email": "Email"
        },
        "Lastname": "Client1Lastname",
        "Firstname": "Client1Firstname",
        "Gender": "f",
        "PriceModel": {
            "Duration": 12,
            "TimebonusDays": 0,
            "RegistrationFee": 0.0,
            "TuitionFee": 45.0,
            "Recurrence": {
                "Id": 1,
                "Name": "monthly",
                "Englishname": "monthly"
            },
            "ModelType": "Time"
        },

    },
        {
        "MembershipType": "Block",
        "ContactData": {
            "Phone1": "Client2Phone",
            "Email": "Client2Email"
            },
        "Lastname": "Client2LastName",
        "Firstname": "Client2FirstName",
        "Gender": "m",
        "PriceModel": {
            "OverallCharges": 10,
            "ChargesLeft": 0,
            "ChargesUsed": 10,
            "ChargeDates": [
                "2011-10-02T11:18:34",
            ],
            "Recurrence": {
                "Id": 2,
                "Name": "advance",
                "Englishname": "advance"
            },
            "ModelType": "Block"
        },
}
]
```

Comment: Could you please add the code that you try to deserialize this JSON to object?

Comment: Selim, I posted the Json. Do you mean something different?

Comment: No, I mean there must be something like this  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` in your code, please post it as well.

Comment: Your json content does have neither `ChargingPriceModel` nor `TimingPriceModel` which you check in your converter. Besides, this json content is probably for some other (parent) class, like `Customer` or `Contact` which `PricingModel` is a property of.  Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Selim, certainly, I have added it in my post

Comment: Oguz, thank you very much for your input! I have (hopefully) fixed the Json example. Of course, you are right, it is part of a customer. I have also fixed the issue with the missing fields. Now, I hit a System.Stakoverflow exception. I suspect an infinite Loop at some point...

Comment: Well, turns out it was the `[JsonConverter(typeof(PriceModelConverter))]` Annotation that caused the infinite loop. Thank you very much, finally solved!